# JavaScript character normalization

Tags: javascript, normalization, character

I'm using Google Translate API, and if I try to translate **Mc Donald's** this is what I get as a result:

**`Mc Donald&#39;s`**

How can I translate **`&#39;`** to **`'`** -- in JavaScript -- and so on for any other numeric character reference?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't something like this do it?

```
'Mc Donald&#39;s'.replace(/&#(\d+);/g, function(m, g) {
  return String.fromCharCode(g);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check those two:

[Javascript equivalent for PHP's html_entity_decode](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/javascript_equivalent_for_phps_html_entity_decode/)

And its dependence:

[Javascript equivalent for PHP's get_html_translation_table](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/javascript_equivalent_for_phps_get_html_translation_table/)

Answer (score 1):

JS libraries often have helper api's for this,  Prototype for example has its unescapeHTML() function on String that works perfect, notice the examples:

http://prototypejs.org/api/string/unescapeHTML